# Storing admin username/password - FLASK-SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy, admin, password-hash, storing-data

I am currently learning programming and do not have much experience yet. I am making a webapp to manage employees (this is a personal project that I am only doing to learn from and is not going to be used by anyone) and I wanted to have a single admin user. I was wondering where I should store the username/password for that user. Even though this is just a personal project, I would learn more from trying to do it correctly, so that it could theoretically be used by someone.

Currently I am just storing the username and password-hash in the code itself, which I imagine is very bad practice.

Comment: Hi! Welcome in SO. To answer you question, you can use [sqlite](https://www.sqlite.org/index.html) to store your user data. There are [tutorial](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-iv-database) that you can use and learn from. You can also use MySQL as your database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are several options that you can do. If you are just getting started, for simplicity's sake, I would recommend you checkout [Flask-User](https://flask-user.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).
For state persistence, I would suggest you work with SQLite through Flask-SQLAlchemy. Don't bother with trying to spool up a whole database server for this.

Comment: Ok, so I should store it in a separate table even though it's just one admin user?